# Javascript functions: checkbox not alerting when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

I'm trying to figure out why the alert boxes and console logs don't work as intended when I check a checkbox.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/4b84f/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="1"/>
<label for="1">One</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="2"/>
<label for="2">Two</label>
</div>

<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="3"/>
<label for="3">Three</label>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
    .loadURL('/URL/path/to/geojson/data/')
    .addTo(map)
    .setFilter(showIfChecked);

$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  showIfChecked();
});

function showIfChecked(feature) {

var parameter_codes = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (var i = 0; i < parameter_codes.length; i++) {

    if ($("#"+parameter_codes[i]).prop("checked")) {
      console.log(this); //shouldn't this return something like "#2" if the second checkbox is checked?
      return (feature.properties["property"] === parameter_codes[i]);
    } else {
      return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Change `click` to `change`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/4b84f/10/

I passed in a reference to the checkbox clicked to the `showIfChecked` method.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  showIfChecked();
});
```

to

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  showIfChecked(this); // this refers to the checkbox element clicked
});
```

Then, I just used the passed in feature/checkbox as a jQuery object to get the id attribute

`alert($(feature).attr('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems: first, you're bailing out of the loop as soon as an item doesn't match. So if `#2` was checked, you examine `#1`, see that it *isn't* checked, and immediately return `false`.

Instead, only return when all options have been checked:

```
for (var i = 0; i < parameter_codes.length; i++) {

  if ($("#"+parameter_codes[i]).prop("checked")) {
    console.log(this); //shouldn't this return something like "#2" if the second checkbox is checked?
    return (feature.properties["property"] === parameter_codes[i]);
  } 
}

return false;
```

As for the `console.log()`, no, you called a global function (`showIfChecked()`), so `this` is `window`. If you want to log the selected item, then:

```
console.log($("#' + parameter_codes[i]));
```

As-is, this code will still blow up since you're looking at the `feature` parameter, but you're not passing that parameter in the call.

```
showIfChecked();
// ...
function showIfChecked(feature) {
  // ...
  return (feature.properties["property"] === parameter_codes[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Your code seems a bit complex.

If you just need to call a function with data from a given element, you can directly pass it to showIfChecked.

```
function showIfChecked(id) {
  console.log(id);
}

$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(event) {
  if ($(event.currentTarget).prop("checked")) {
    showIfChecked((event.currentTarget.id));
  }
});
```